# How to wrap big integer definition to comply with pep8?

Tags: python, pep8

my code contains this line, which is only a (big) integer initialization:

```
myvalue = 0xcc9e4307e00db722fc71e019c7c74c3cd23e056d0c7cb683b9e3c1549eee3d309a6106f819417701108b9424247cc5e97a8c963a4c493573ab12d890f221d495
```

When I run pep8 on the script, I get a `E501 line too long`.

What is the most convenient way to have my code pep8-compliant?

Comment: Add a pragma telling the linter to ignore the line? PEP8 is a *guideline*, not a requirement.

Comment: If using pylint, the directives would be `# pylint: disable=line-too-long` and `# pylint enable=line-too-long`

Answer (score 8):

Integer literals can't be broken across multiple lines. Your options are, in order of preference:

1. Add a pragma telling the linter to ignore the line. PEP8 is a *guideline*, not a requirement.
2. Calculate the number from smaller parts.
3. Convert from a string using `int('..', 16)`, where you break the string over multiple lines.

You should also consider moving the number out of your python code altogether; move it into a configuration file read at start-up, for example.

Comment: I agree with your first point, so it's kind of moot, but I'd move the integer to a configuration file before doing 2. or 3.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida: added that as a separate consideration, since the OP is talking about including the number in their code.